# Usage of tense in sentences with "in case"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, tenses

"I will give you a map in case you **get** lost."

"I will give you a map in case **you will be getting** lost."

Which use of the tenses of the bold portions of the above two sentences is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'In case' is one of the conjunctions /like 'if', 'unless', etc./ which is used with conditional clauses.
In conditional clauses we must use Present Tenses with the future reference, which is seen in the main clause.
For example:
Be ready in case he calls you.
I'll let you know in case l hear from him.